# How to flash a custom recovery with heimdall (without touching the main system)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, heimdall

The first recommended step in [the installation of CyanogenMod on Samsung Galaxy S](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd) is flashing a custom recovery like ClockworkMod or the one from Replicant with a command like:

```
heimdall flash --kernel path/to/recovery.img
```

Now I feel that the instructions might be misleading:

I have done the first step wanting just to have a custom recovery mode, without proceeding to replacing the main OS on the device.

It seems I have done that wrong, because the device now always boots into the recovery mode.

What would be the correct heimdall command to just install a custom recovery system without touching the main system?

Comment: [BTW, is there a way to restore booting into the old main system now?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41709/13117)

Comment: It worked for me. But AFAIK it depends on the version of the stock ROM you have: Some custom recoveries are able to boot it, others not. I guess there is no general way.

Comment: @Flow So, the recovery mode and the normal mode are supposed to use the same image when booting? I was thinking that perhaps there are two different images for the different boot modes, and I replaced the wrong one by mistake, and that's the source of my problem: booting always into the recovery system (no matter whether other keys are pressed when powering up) after I executed the flashing command from the post, although I would really like to boot the old main system.

Comment: No, if the custom kernel/recovery boots always into recovery then it's usually a sign that it is unable to find/boot the normal system.

Comment: He just needed to rerun print-pit cmd, then flash his boot.img into the partition where he'd flashed recovery.img, no? In my experience, they are almost always right next to each other.

Answer (score 16):

It depends on your PIT partition file.

Before you do anything using heimdall, print the partition table of your phone.

```
sudo heimdall print-pit
```

The output of the file is the location assigned to each partition. For example on my Galaxy S3, I have something like this:

```
--- Entry #20 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 19
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 491520
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Kernel2
Flash Filename: recovery.img
FOTA Filename:
```

Now this tells me 3 main things:

- Name the flash file: `recovery.img`
- Location of the identifier `19`
- And finally the name of the recovery partition `Kernel2`

**What does this means?**

This means if I want to flash a recovery image I should use either the identifier 19, or the name Kernel2.

```
sudo heimdall flash --19 any-type-of-recovery.img
```

or

```
sudo heimdall flash --Kernel2 any-type-of-recovery.img
```

**Bottom Line:** Look at the pit file to figure out where to flash your recovery.

Cheers,
Mel

Comment: Just a note for others, if the `recovery.img` flash is successful but you let your device reboot as normal straight after, the boot image will likely remove the custom recovery image. Either use `adb` or use the recovery mode key combination as soon as heimdall is successful.

Answer (score 4):

One effective way with Heimdall is to just run

`sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp.img`

Worked for me on an S3 AT&T

Then when phone reboots, go into recovery via

`adb reboot recovery`

Comment: I also used `--no-reboot` flag. Otherwise the system booted and later on an official recovery seemed to be reinstalled so I couldn't enter TWRP. And thank You by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the partition mapping of the SGS, so my only suggestion would be to use the GUI (heimdall-frontend) and select the recovery partition only. As of restoration of the original system, my suggestion is to reflash the original ROM without touching /data. But backup it first using an advanced custom recovery like this one if possible: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2201860 (the key feature is custom backup/restore)

Comment: But what if I destroy the original OS when flashing the custom recovery? In my case, I flashed a custom recovery, but the OS doesn't boot after that... swhat could go wrong? That is something I didn't expect: I just wantee to flash a custom recovery, but do not install a new main OS. Now I'm forced to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
heimdall flash --Recovery /Path/recovery.img --Kernel /Path/recovery.img
```

Replicant OS Recovery install