# Samsung Galaxy S3 Keeps shutting off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I just recently found an old Samsung phone and I have been trying to get it to boot up. I have some old pictures of my kids on there I would love to get off of it. The phone tries to boot up but as soon as it gets to the Galaxy S3 logo it shuts down. I charged the battery and it works fine (checked it with another S3) I tried the Power button, volume down, home button and it gets to the point where I can choose to reset the phone and it goes to the android logo then shuts down. The volume up option shows that it begins the boot recovery but then it shuts down. Any ideas? It had become my mission to figure this out, but it is looking like it might be a lost cause.

Comment: check the device modelno GT-I9300 from download mode and flash official [twrp](https://twrp.me) recovery according to your device model [How to flash a custom recovery with heimdall](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44106)

Comment: don't mix up with S3 Neo GT-I9301i