# How to know if a broken screen phone has been factory reset?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, broken-screen

I have an old Samsung phone with a broken screen and pass code but before I try to unlock my phone I want to know if there is any possible way to know if it has been factory reset because if it has then I won't need to open it.
I would also like to add that I have a different phone that has been factory reset so is there anyway to know if it has a backup?

Comment: How old? some phones can be flashed on locked bootloader, means availbility to flash adb enabled boot or recovery. some phones aren't encrypted, allowing raw dump of userdata partition

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure but it looks quite old, it has a duos symbol in the right hand corner and it's smaller than Tha palm of my hand with a rectangular Shape. Can I send u a Pic?

Comment: this should work for any Spreadtrum chipset, except no fastboot available, but you can gather information from heimdall and/or custom recovery (or even dump/flash boot partition straight from adb commands while on custom recovery) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232319

Comment: [combination firmware](https://www.bigfirmware.com/j105h-combination-file) should have adb enabled by default, can be flashed without data loss. [SuperSU](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu) for j1minive3g should work too, but not sure about this will wipe data

Comment: you should be able to reach [download mode](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-j105h-galaxy-j1-mini/download-mode) and flash [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4000225) custom recovery with [heimdall](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44106). you can't copy files if device is encrypted, but you can modify boot or system from twrp adb shell. report back once you have adb shell, will give you instructions

Comment: First of all thx for all your help.     I'm not gonna lie tho but you seem very knowledgeable on the subject and I really barely understood anything (no offense, I just don't know much) so in summary I just need to find and download "adb shell" on my pc and then come back?

Comment: follow first link and download platform-tools. use any mobile phone for testing. enable usb-debugging in developer options and connect usb cable. execute adb.exe `adb devices` and authorize connection on phone screen. now you should be able to open `adb shell` you will see `$` prompt. you can browse files for example `cd /sdcard` and `ls`. now you understand how successful adb looks like. you can now connect the broken phone and see if adb devices show something (probably not). But you can follow my last comment and flash TWRP. after flashing, boot into recovery and check adb shell is working