# Does upgrading bootloader wipe your data?

Tags: updates, bootloader

I'm about to flash an update to Android 4.4.2 on my Nexus 4, downloaded from Google Developers, and one of the files that it's going to flash is the new bootloader version.

I wanted to know if flashing a new bootloader will re-lock my fastboot, which will require me to unlock it wiping my data, or if it will in any other way cause my data to be wiped.

Comment: It should not AFAIK, but a backup won't hurt.

Comment: I'm with @Izzy - a backup is always a good idea in these cases, and not just because of a potential wipe. For example, what if something goes wrong and stuff breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made a backup in case and then I performed the upgrade.

End result: **It did not wipe my data**. It did not re-lock my fastboot, or any other side effect that I could find except updating the bootloader version either.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @bmdixon, it seems this *is* the answer. He ran the update and it did not wipe his data.