# How to flash and root OnePlus 3T on Linux?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, supersu, oneplus-3

I Recently bought a `OnePlus 3T` and want to flash and root it.

Most resource focus on `OnePlus3` and on Windows.

How do I do that on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gather the steps in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/44d14602e9c30490513b9f5aa12300fb).

---

## How to flash and root OnePlus 3T on Linux

### Update

- 2017-jan-05:

  - fix `SuperSU` with  [`no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip`](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt/no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip) and [`SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip`](https://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip)² ;

### Requirements

> **Disclaimer:** I've already done those kind of install on different phones and I'm familiar with the steps. So be sure to read the resources to get an understanding of what happens.

- [ ] battery are `>60%` ;
- [ ] **know what you are doing?**
- [ ] remember that version used worked **for me**.

Screenshots are not mine, thanks to their author.

### Flashing Recovery to TWRP

> Flashing require to do a factory reset. Backup your data.

#### Prepare Phone

1. **enable `Developer Options`**

   1. in `Settings` -> `About Phone` -> `Build Number` (at the bottom)
   2. by tap on it for 5-7 times to enable Developer Options
2. enable `USB Debugging`

   1. in `Settings` -> `Developer Options` -> `USB Debugging.`
3. enable `OEM Unlocking` (in the same list).

   [developer-options http://cdn3.freeandroidroot.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Enable-OEM-Unlock-USB-Debugging.jpg](http://cdn3.freeandroidroot.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Enable-OEM-Unlock-USB-Debugging.jpg)
4. Install `adb` and `fastboot` tooling:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
   ```
5. Reboot to bootloader either with <s>`adb reboot bootloader`</s> or through power button ;
6. Unlock the bootloader:

   ```
   sudo fastboot oem unlock
   ```
7. Flash the recovery with `TWRP`:

   ```
   sudo fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.3-0-oneplus3t.img
   ```
8. Reboot to recovery to *wipe cache* ;
9. Reboot to recovery to *mount* the device ;
10. Download SuperSU and no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip

    - [`SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip`](https://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip) (the `2.79`² didn't worked for me) ;
    - [`no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip`](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt/no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip) (`dm-verity` and forced encryption disabler).
11. Copy to your smartphone *Internal Storage* directory (using *nautilus* or *nemo*¹) ;
12. install both of them with `TWRP` ;
13. reboot and **enjoy!**

### Root

> The rooting procedure given here is not a data-loss process but it won’t hurt to have a backup of your smartphone’s personal data.
>
> [source](http://freeandroidroot.com/root-oneplus-3t/)

### Resources

- [How To Flash TWRP Recovery And Root OnePlus 3T](http://freeandroidroot.com/root-oneplus-3t/) - freeandroidroot ;
- [How to root opt using Linux](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-root-opt-using-linux.417046/) - forums.oneplus.net ;
- [OnePlus 3T: How to Unlock Bootloader | Flash TWRP | Root](https://devs-lab.com/oneplus-3t-unlock-bootloader-twrp-root.html) - devs-lab.com ;
- Direct link to [working version of `SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip`](https://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip) - download.chainfire.eu.
- Direct link to [`no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip`](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt/no-verity-opt-encrypt-5.0.zip) - build.nethunter.com.

### Footnote

- ¹: I didn't manage to access my smartphone storage with `Dolphin` ;
- ²: `SR1-SuperSU-v2.79-SR1-20161221223537` didn't work for me.

Comment: I have a problem with step 6. After step 5 I assume you want to reboot in fastboot mode. Can you tell me what is you USB device id (`lsusb`) when you are in fastboot mode? Mine didn't change. I'm stuck right now, cannot issue `fastboot oem unlock` because there's no fastboot device. I still see my phone as an ADB device. Should I switch it to MTP or PTP mode instead of USB debug when try to fastboot unlcok or flash?

Comment: @CsabaToth in step 5 you reboot in fastboot indeed to unlock the device. my device id is `2a70:9011`. I never used MTP/PTP for this flash/rooting.
What do you mean by "I'm stuck"?

Comment: I'm stuck=`fastboot devices` doesn't show my device, returns empty. `adb devices` shows my phone and it's USB id is still the regular `05c6`. Somehow I cannot boot to fastboot? I don't understand. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169509/why-fastboot-devices-is-empty-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: I get `2a70:9011` USB device when I switch the phone to MTP USB mode. (With PTP ot's `2a70:904e`). Unfortunately `fastboot devices` shows nothing still. What is your udev configuration please?

Comment: I added `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="2a70", MODE="0666"` and
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a70", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`. For regular USB debug I have these rules with `05c6`

Comment: When I reboot to fastboot, the phone ask my PIN, and then it boots up and looks normal.

Comment: What distro and what version you use? I'm with Yakkety Yak 16.10 Ubuntu. I used the Android SDK's platform-tools, but now I installed distro's `android-tools-fastboot` but that doesn't see the device either.

Comment: @CsabaToth I use Linux Mint 18.1 Serena and installed `android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

Comment: Maybe I should try a LiveCD...