# A Daydream of OnePlus 3T

Tags: oneplus-3, oxygenos

According to Carl Pei (OnePlus CEO) are there no plans to add support for Google's Daydream VR platform to there latest smartphone, the OnePlus 3T.

So my question is, is the OnePlus 3T nevertheless capable of running the Daydream VR Environment (App & Controller) without hacks?

*There is a [hack for the OnePlus 3](http://www.daydreamdistrict.com/run-daydream-vr-oneplus-3/), which involves rooting and side-loading, which i would really want to avoid.*

Answer (score 2):

Without One Plus guys adding support there will be no direct way to do this.
however rooting is one of the ways but I would prefer not to do so.

Comment: Some videos say it's enough to just root and change the xml config file. Some forums say it won't work without unlocking the bootloader, which means full backup and wipe. What's the truth? And does the 1+3 trick work on 1+3t?

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the hack for O+3 (2 extra XML config lines) should work for O+3t as well. Rooting + side loading part: [How to flash and root OnePlus 3T on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166033/how-to-flash-and-root-oneplus-3t-on-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

I managed to get it working during the summer, but during the fall the hack stopped working after an OS update :(.