# Why fastboot devices is empty on Linux?

Tags: linux, oneplus-3

I'm using Ubuntu Yakkety Yak, 16.10.

According to Android SDK manager:
Android SDK Tools v 25.0.3
Android Build Tools v 25.0.2
Android SDK Tools v 25.2.5

My phone is a OnePlus 3**t** and I'm developing for it for a while, `adb` works normally, `udev` rules are configured. I enabled OEM boot, and manage to reboot in a way which looks like to me fastboot. After rebooting to "fastboot" the device's USB id is exactly the same as in normal boot. That's suspicious because I read in some forums that it might be different after fastboot boot (I checked if I have to adjust `udev` rules).

```
fastboot devices
```

doesn't show any devices. My suspicion is that I don't really boot into fastboot mode. Here is capture when I reboot, I press the power button:

[image: fastboot screen capture]

If I don't press the power button, the up/down offers recovery mode. In recovery mode I can wipe all data or the cache and also install from internal storage or ADB. data decrypts successfully. Needless to say I cannot install SuperSU, TWRP img doesn't appear in that install menu.

(My goal is to unlock the bootloader, install `TWRP` and `SuperSU` so I can perform the `xml` file config mod for DayDream.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm amazed BTW how nicely OnePlus is tinkerable as opposed to my old Galaxy Note for example. I'm sure it's some glitch with my setup we'll overcome soon.

Comment: Found someone who did it successfully: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166033/how-to-flash-and-root-oneplus-3t-on-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I disconnected the device while I was rebooting.

Comment: The screenshot is fastboot, you should be able to unlock and then install TWRP image.

Comment: I know. But `fastboot devices` shows nothing so I cannot issue the `oem unlock`. I'll try to tinker until I succeed.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with your `udev` conf but I didn't need any of that. It worked out of the box.

Comment: The USB device during fastboot BTW is `18d1:d00d Google Inc.` and I needed to add udev rule for TWRP flashing. Thanks for your efforts BTW!

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood what does it mean to boot to fastboot mode. By reading through tutorials I thought when I saw the screen on the screenshot, I still needed to boot (power button) into fastboot mode. Turns out that when I saw that screen above, I was already in fastboot mode and could issue the unlock or flash commands.

Looking at some more detailed Youtube videos made that clear. After tackling a typo I successfully flashed TWRP, installed SuperSU. The OP3 DayDream mod is not working yet though: DayDream apps still displayed as not compatible with my phone in the app store, even after the XML modification and reboot.

One extra advice: a simple `adb backup -all` won't backup everything, as I learned.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3t/help/oneplus-3t-fastboot-ubuntu-16-10-t3561732?goto=newpost

---

During 2017 summer I managed to get the DayDream hack working, I used SuperSU. I just transitioned to Magisk, so I can use Android Pay and hardware tokens. The DayDream hack does not work since the last couple of OS updates in the fall.